# Looping through an array while sending data

Tags: php, sql, laravel

I am sending query data to an email through the following function.

```php
$adminInfo = Visit::whereDate('created_at', Carbon::today())
    ->get()
    ->toArray();

Mail::send('mails.mails2', ['data' => json_encode($adminInfo)], function ($message) {
    $message->from('', '');
    $message->to('');
    $message->subject('Visitor arrived');
});
```

It displays the data as an array but I want to display this data in a table. When I attempt to do that I get an error.

```php
@foreach ($data as $day)
    <label>{{$day['id']}}</label>
@endforeach
```

Comment: [offtopic] You should anonimize the email addresses you're using...

Comment: could you please add your error

Answer (score 0):

I'm just guessing, because you haven't posted the error message.

The function `json_encode()` turns your `$adminInfo` into a `JSON-string`, but to use the `foreach loop` you need an `array`. So you could try to pass `$adminInfo` directly to your email template, without encoding it. (You already called `toArray()` on your Collection, so this will be an array)